# How to remove a Z shell precmd function?

Tags: ubuntu, zsh

I have a few functions in my `Z shell` `precmd` function list.

I can see them with

```
echo $precmd_functions
```

In this list I can see a function called `_ntfy_precmd`

How can I remove it from the function list?

(This function was added after installing https://github.com/dschep/ntfy)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just as with adding functions to `precmd` you have two choices:

1. Directly manipulate the `precmd_functions` array:

   ```
   precmd_functions=(${precmd_functions:#_ntfy_precmd})
   ```

   The `${name:#pattern}` parameter expansion, when used on an array, removes all elements matching `pattern` from the expansion of `name`.
2. Use the `add-zsh-hook` utility to remove functions from the hook functions lists:

   ```
   add-zsh-hook -d precmd _ntfy_precmd
   ```

   If `zsh` tells you that there is no `add-zsh-hook` command, you can load it with

   ```
   autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
   ```

---

BTW: You can list the functions with `add-zsh-hook -L [HOOK]`, too.